# How to get one iteration printed in a nested loop

Tags: python, loops, nested

I have a nested loop in python:

```py
append_str = "//mycomment "

for item in runfile:   
    for item1 in flat_common_list: 
        item1 = item1[1:-1]  ## remove double quotes otherwise match wont work
        if item1 in item:
            pre_comment = append_str + item 
            runfile_final.write(pre_comment)
        else:
            runfile_final.write(item)
            break
```

My goal is to print all "items" in "runfile" once but prefix `//mycomment`  to the matching lines with `item1` in `flat_common_list`. Eventually write the results to `runfile_final`.

With the current code, it's working but only for the first match and then breaks. If I don't add a break, then everything is repeated in nested loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `break` up to the case where the item matches and then dedent your `else` so that it only runs if the `for` *doesn't* break. If an item matches, you write once then break. If no items match, the else prints the original item. I moved stripping the quotes out of the loop so it is only done once.

```
append_str = "//mycomment "

# strip quotes from common list values for later match
fixed_common_list = [val[1:-1] for val in flat_common_list]

for item in runfile:   
    for item1 in flat_common_list: 
        if item1 in item:
            pre_comment = append_str + item 
            runfile_final.write(pre_comment)
            break
    else:
        runfile_final.write(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to organise your loops a bit differently. Keep track of the value you want to write to `runfile_final`, then write it once you are out of the inner loop:

```
for item in runfile:
    modified_item = item
    for item1 in flat_common_list:
        item1 = item1[1:-1]
        if item1 in item:
            modified_item = append_str + item
            break
    runfile_final.write(modified_item)
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered by clicking the check mark next to the answer if it solved your issue.